# generic functionality to open bootstrap $modal with Object values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have created controller to open $modal . now how to make common method to open $modal . also i need to pass some object to $modal template .

Below i have created controller which i can you as a common method . but , i need to pass object data while opening $modal [without using factory ]

**HTML:**

```
<a class="view-all" href="#" ng-controller="MoreDetailControllerbasic" 
  ng-click="get_form('login')">+ add more</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    viewmoreApp.controller('MoreDetailControllerbasic', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', '$modal',
    function($scope, $http, $compile, $modal) {

        $scope.data="i am trying to send this Dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        $scope.get_form = function(form) { 
            debugger;
            $scope.form = form;
            templateUrl = "/form/" + form + ' ';

            modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl : '/view_more',
                controller : 'MoreDetailController',
                //backdrop : 'static'
                resolve: {
                        GalleryData: function () {
                            return $scope.data;
                        },

                    }

            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                //Get triggers when modal is closed
            }, function() {

                //gets triggers when modal is dismissed.
            });

        };


    }]);

    viewmoreApp.controller('MoreDetailController', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', '$modalInstance','GalleryData',
    function($scope, $http, $compile, $modalInstance,GalleryData) {
        $scope.data_list=GalleryData;
        $scope.greetings="Welcome to wiki ";
        $scope.closeModal = function() { debugger;
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    }]);
```

Comment: Maybe you need `scope` property?

Comment: @dfsq i am trying to make directive for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating a directive and passion data in attribute.

```
viewmoreApp.directive("viewMore", ['$cookies', '$http', '$compile', '$timeout', '$modal',
function($cookies, $http, $compile, $timeout, $modal) {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        scope : {
             mySelection: "@",
        },
        template : "<div>Click For More</div>",
        controller : function($scope, $element, $attrs, $compile) {
            alert('directive init()');
            $element.bind('click', function() {

                modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl : '/view_more',
                    controller : 'MoreDetailController',
                    //backdrop : 'static'
                    resolve : {
                        GalleryData : function() {
                            return $attrs.mySelection;
                        },
                    }

                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                    //Get triggers when modal is closed
                }, function() {

                    //gets triggers when modal is dismissed.
                });
            });

        },
        replace : true,
        transclude : true,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
        }
    };
}]);
```